# Code igniter how to save browser info and url in error logs file on hit of any page or url?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have created **error log file** in code igniter and it's working fine. **There are most of error for page not found like**

> ERROR - 2020-09-26 00:16:33 --> 404 Page Not Found: Vendor/phpunit
> ERROR - 2020-19-26 15:23:10 --> 404 Page Not Found: Wp-content/plugins

I need to track from where these url's are hit. So i want to save the url and user agent in log file. Is it possible in code igniter? I am trying it to create a log file in library folder and this is my code

```
class MY_Log extends CI_Log  
{

    function MY_Log ()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->ci =& get_instance();
    }
    public function write_log() 
    { 
        if ($this->_enabled === FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $level = strtoupper($level);

        if ( ! isset($this->_levels[$level]) OR
        ($this->_levels[$level] > $this->_threshold))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        /* HERE YOUR LOG FILENAME YOU CAN CHANGE ITS NAME */
        $filepath = $this->_log_path.'log-'.date('Y-m-d').EXT;
        $message  = '';

        if ( ! file_exists($filepath))
        {
            $message .= "<"."?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH'))
            exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?".">\n\n";
        }

        if ( ! $fp = @fopen($filepath, FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE))
        {
        return FALSE;
        }

        $message .= $level.' '.(($level == 'INFO') ? ' -' : '-').' ';
        $message .= date($this->_date_fmt). ' --> '.$msg."\n";
        log_message('error','custom error');

        flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
        fwrite($fp, $message);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);

        @chmod($filepath, FILE_WRITE_MODE);
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your error logs

> ERROR - 2020-09-26 00:16:33 --> 404 Page Not Found: Vendor/phpunit ERROR - 2020-19-26 15:23:10 --> 404 Page Not Found: Wp-content/plugins

These are common bots looking for security holes in websites, it is very common on published urls. I suggest you look into apache's error log instead, from there the agent and ip address are usually recorded, you can then block those IPs if you have firewall on your server.

If you use apache on centos, look for the file in :

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log
```